# If half of the UK's household wealth is owned by 10% of them, do we know anything about the mean?

Tags: statistics, means

A very simple question on maths:

- If half of the UK's household wealth is owned by 10% of them, is the
  cut off to that 10% the mean household wealth?

Comment: obviously NOT http://www.theguardian.com/business/2016/jan/18/richest-62-billionaires-wealthy-half-world-population-combined

Answer (score 0):

No.  We know that the mean of the upper $10\%$ is nine times the mean of the lower $90\%$, but that is all.  That also says the overall mean is $1.8$ times the mean of the lower $90\%$.  We could have $9$ people with $1$ and $1$ person with $9$ for an overall mean of $1.8$  We could have $8$ people with $1$, $1$ people with $5$, and $1$ person with $13$.  The mean is then $2.6$.

Comment: It looks like you're saying that the mean is 1.8...